# Explanation of the formula $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in A |f(x) \in Y\}$ for the preimage of a set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

So I found a Definition in the book that goes like this to find the pre-image of a set:

$$f^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in A |f(x) \in Y\}$$

Example of the theorem being used:

> Let $A  = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $B = \{6,7,8,9,10\}$, then the cartesian product of those two     sets can be seen with $f = \{(3,8),(4,6)\}$. Therefore, for $D = \{6,8\}$, we have $f^{-1}(D) = \{3,4\}$

Can someone explain to me how the bolded part of this formula $f^{-1}(Y)=\{x \in A| \mathbf{f(x) \in Y}\}$ works? I don't understand how plugging in $x$ into the function $f$ makes it an element of $Y$. Can someone show me a visual representation of what they mean by $\mathbf{f(x) \in Y}$ in this case, by using the numbers in the example I wrote? Thanks.

Comment: It's a definition, it means find all things that end up in $Y$ after you do $f$ to them.

Comment: Can you show me one example of it with this example please?

Comment: I'm just confused because in my example, 6 ∈ A, but what is f(6) ∈ y mean when I don't know what f is doing to 6.

Comment: I just don't get the f(x) ∈ y part in the definition

Comment: It means the **number** $f(x)$ is in the **set** $Y$.

Comment: I see, then why is f(3) ∈ D? D = {6,8}, but it has no 3 in it.

Comment: There is an error somewhere in the problem. As given, that particular $f$ is not a function. You should ask whoever gave you the problem to clarify:  as-stated not even element from the domain has an image.

Comment: I reformatted the question. Please see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for this site. For example, $f(x)\in Y$ is typed as `$f(x)\in Y$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rough terms, if we have a function that maps elements of A to elements of B, the pre-image of B $f^{-1}(B)$ is *defined* to be the set of all elements of A *such that the function maps them to elements of B* (the vertical bar in set notation is read to mean "such that").

To use the *x* and *Y* notation you use near the end of your question, *making* *x* into an element of *Y* by applying the function comes for free if *x* is in the pre-image, since the pre-image is *defined* to be the set of *x* 's that map to elements of Y.

Using your example, we are *given* that the function *f* defined on the cartesian product $A \times B$ maps 3 to 8 and 4 to 6. Thus the pre-image of the subset of B with elements {6, 8} (call this subset B*) is precisely the subset of A with elements {3,4}, which we can call A*. Thus $f^{-1}$(B*) = A*. However, if we defined a second function on $A \times B$, say *g*, that maps 2 to 10, then we could say the pre-image of the subset of B called B' = {10} for the function *g* has pre-image {2}. That is, $g^{-1}(B')$ = {2}.

**Note:** As most of the comments suggest, the function $f: A \rightarrow B$ as defined in the book example (and the function *g* in mine) is not truly a function in the rigorous sense, since not all elements of A are mapped uniquely to elements of B. What is given is essentially a subset of the function *f* (which itself is a strict subset of the cartesian product $A \times B$). This becomes an issue if there are multiple elements in A, some of which that aren't given, that map to the subset of interest in B. To use the example again, consider the function *f*. If there are elements in A other than 4 that map to 6, we are in trouble. We can't know whether or not this is the case unless the function is fully defined.

Answer (score 0):

If that is in a textbook, it's a horrible example. The cartesian product of the sets $A$ and $B$ is really the set of all possible combinations $(x \in A, y \in B)$. So I don't "see" the cartesian product in what is written. It's like they gave you two possible $(x,y)$ elements from the cartesian product,
$f=\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\}$ and somehow called this a function (?) and simply show that $f^{-1}(y_1,y_2) = (x_1,x_2)$.

I'm tempted to agree with Adam the commenter and say that this makes no sense. If the function is defined on the cartesian product (like the first response says), then elements in the domain should be two element sets with elements coming from both sets, no?

Comment: It's a textbook that even my professor has admitted to be horrible, but it is the only one suitable for the curriculum that I am taking.

Comment: Would you care to post the title and author of this book? Or it's ISBN if it has one.